# Individual current limits for each of 3 lanes

Tags: current, motor, switches

I want to be able to limit the current going through each of 3 channels, for a reaction wheel driver. Each lane should be rated for the maximum current draw of each motor, and the real feature: *If one lane blows, they all blow*

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This isn't a free design service. Please improve your post by asking a specific question.

Comment: And I know that you could use 3-phase motor overload protection, but is there a way to do this in (relatively) solid state? Of course, barring the relays required to switch the motor power... I have the following idea: Sense current draw in each lane. If no current draw detected and lane should be on, disable ALL lanes. I already have a microcontroller controlling these, so it shouldn't be a problem to integrate this functionality into it. But, if anyone has a better/simpler solution (doubt it), then feel free to share it!

Comment: Please integrate your comment into your post by editing.

Comment: What V, I rating?

Comment: Closing.  There isn't even a question here!  What is here is mostly hand waving.  How do the *channels*, *motors*, and *lanes* relate?  What exactly are these *channels* and *lanes*?  What's a *reaction wheel driver*?  What exactly is supposed to blow?  Sounds like a fuse, but nothing like that was mentioned.  -1 because it should have been obvious that much context and several definitions are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Since fuses are isolated, one option is a 3 phase breaker.

e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Power-Distribution-Circuit-Breakers-3-Pole-Breakers/N-5yc1vZbm1s